# Php while loop ends after continue

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, continue

I have problem with my script. I need send mail when my $sended variable is set on 0, if is set to 1 than i need to ignore this statemant

```
<?php
while ($result = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        if($result['howMany'] == "0") {
          if ($sended == "0") {
            //send mail to admin with info that product was end.
            //this is work fine
            if($mail->send()) {
              //change in my database variable $sended to 1;
              //this is work fine to.
              //if i live it empty, it is work, but if I change $sended to 1, it is not working
            }
          }
          // if variable $result['howMany'] is equal to 0 than i need to end this iteration of while loop.
          continue;
        }

        //rest of script that should work when $result['howMany'] != "0"
}
?>
```

Problem is when $sended variable is set to 0, continue is ending whole loop not only this one iteration. When $sended == 1, than everything is working just fine. Continue work fine. What do I do wrong? Where's error because i dont see it. Sorry for my english. It is not my native language.

Comment: The `continue` is outside of the `if ($sended == "0") {}` block so the 2 are not related.

Answer (score 0):

You should use if-else statement I this way:

```
while ($result = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$temp = false;
if($result['howMany'] == "0") {    
    if ($sended == "0") {
        //send mail to admin with info that product was end.
        //this is work fine
        if($mail->send()) {
          //change in my database variable $sended to 1;
          //this is work fine to.
        }
      }
     else
      {
        $temp = true;
      }
    }
 // use outside all if-else but inside loop
 $temp == true ? continue : false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. Another question. Why i cannot use continue in shorthand if statmant?

Comment: `You can't use continue with if (not even a labelled one) because if isn't an iteration statement;`

Comment: I mean.. i cannot use ```$temp == true ? continue : false;``` I need use ```if (statement) {continue;} else {...}```

Comment: *You can't use continue with if*, it has nothing to do with being in an `if`, as long as you are (in this case) in a `while`, that is the loop it's using.

Answer (score 0):

`$sended` is not defined in your code.

You could select directly to see which stock is empty (WHERE howMany = 0) then build out an email and send rather than selecting all then doing the check-in the loop.

Or if you would like to do like you're doing, set a flag to send, build the email and then send at the end after the loop, it will allow you to build out the email body as surely you don't want to send an email for every item out of stock when a single email would suffice.

```
<?php
$pdo = new class {
    public $rows = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'Product' => 'Toilet Rolls',
            'howMany' => 0,
            'sended' => 0
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'Product' => 'Baked Beans',
            'howMany' => 7,
            'sended' => 0
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'Product' => 'Sugar Puffs',
            'howMany' => 0,
            'sended' => 1
        ],
    ];
    
    public function fetch() {
        return array_pop($this->rows);
    }
};

$mail = new class {
    public $to = '';
    public $subject = '';
    public $body = '';
    public $debug = false;
    
    public function send() {
        if ($this->debug) echo "Sending email:\nTo: {$this->to}\nSubject: {$this->subject}\nBody: {$this->body}".PHP_EOL;
        
        return true;
    }
};


$stockEmail = [
  'body' => '',
  'shouldSend' => false    
];

while ($result = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    // got stock with no items and not sended
    if (!$result['howMany'] && !$result['sended']) {
        
        // flag to send
        $stockEmail['shouldSend'] = true;
        
        // email body (header)
        if (empty($stockEmail['body'])) {
            $stockEmail['body'] .= 'Hello, Mr Stockman!'.PHP_EOL;
            $stockEmail['body'] .= 'The following stock is empty, re-ordering is required:'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        
        // email body (continuation)
        $stockEmail['body'] .= ' - '.$result['Product'].PHP_EOL;
        
        // do database update with $result['id']
        // UPDATE stock SET sended = 1 WHERE id = ?
    }
}

// has stock email
if ($stockEmail['shouldSend']) {
    $mail->debug = true;
    $mail->to = 'stockman@acme.company.example.com';
    $mail->from = 'stockcontrol@acme.company.example.com';
    $mail->subject = 'Stock control message';
    $mail->body = $stockEmail['body'];
    
    
    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo 'Stock control email sent!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error sending stock control email!';
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Sending email:
To: stockman@acme.company.example.com
Subject: Stock control message
Body: Hello, Mr Stockman!
The following stock is empty, re-ordering is required:
 - Toilet Rolls

Stock control email sent!
```